# jqGrid: change background Image in the header of grid

Tags: jqgrid, background, header

I have a jqGrid and it comes with default background image, I want to change the background image of it.  I tried couple of ways as suggested in online

METHOD 1. I added below code in my CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header
{
    background-image:url(images/my-header.png) repeat-x !important;
}
```

METHOD 2.Added below code to load complete event of jqGrid

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    $("#gview_jqgCUST .ui-jqgrid-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');
    $("#gview_jqgCUST .ui-jqgrid-titlebar").addClass('jqgrid-header');
}
```

in CSS I added

```css
.jqgrid-header{
    background:red url(images/my-header.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:Blue;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

and I am loading css files after jqGrid css file but could not achieve it

How can I do it ?? Any sample code please... I am new to jqGrid and jQuery..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can use [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) of jQuery UI to customize theme which you use on the page. You can reduce the applying of the theme only to a paer of your page by usage of "CSS Scope" (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052755/315935)).

Alternatively you can specify `background` of `.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header`. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackgroundImageInHeader.htm) uses [the background](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/images//ui-bg_diagonals-thick_15_0b3e6f_40x40.png) from "Dot Luv" theme. Additional to `background` I specified colors of the text and the border to make the look of header better. I used CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #0b3e6f;
    background: #0b3e6f url(http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/images//ui-bg_diagonals-thick_15_0b3e6f_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

The resulting grid looks like on the picture below

[image]