# jqGrid with jQuery UI Theme and Font Awesome showing 2 versions of each icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm using jqGrid and *attempting* (I think) to use Font Awesome icons. I am using bootstrap 3.0 [Ace theme](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR) which came pre-packed with the jqGrid files along with font awesome and a function to replace the icons with font awesome icons.

The problem is, the grid is showing 2 versions of each icon when I include [jQuery UI lightness theme](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css) for a different feature on the webpage. If I don't link this theme css file, the grid looks fine.

But, I need the theme css file or an unrelated feature doesn't look right.

What am I doing wrong here? Why, when I link the jQuery lightness ui theme css file, does my jqGrid show 2 of each icon in the table?

If you want to see code, [here](http://bit.ly/1cuncJF) is an example of the original jqgrid and [here](http://bit.ly/1kE2Bwi) is what it looks like when I reference the jQuery ui theme. (See STACKOVERFLOW comment in the code).

[jqGrid with double icons image http://bit.ly/1gPW7ow](http://bit.ly/1gPW7ow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I correctly understand your problem. I suppose that Ace theme is already one jQuery UI Theme which uses Font Awesome icons. So it seems to my that you have just the problem with **the usage of two jQuery UI Theme on one page**. In the case you should download the second Theme (jQuery UI lightness theme) with some non-empty "CSS Scope" and then uses the scope class in an outer div for area on the page where you need use the second theme. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052755/315935) for details. In the way including of the second theme (jQuery UI lightness) will be not applied on the first part of your page where you use Ace theme.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I went down this path and it was looking promising. I ended up taking google's UI lightness theme, re-downloading it using the link mentioned in their file and uploading the css file to my server. When I added the scope it looked a little better but was obviously missing some css. Then I took the scope thing off and re-uploaded and then it looks fine. Not sure how this fixed it because I theoretically should've generated the exact same css file doing this....